# last image in Camera Roll not shown when method called outside viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I'm using a code snippet to get the last image from Camera Roll. I've made a method and I'm calling it in `viewDidLoad` method. I'm using this functionality to share the last image through Social Framework when I hit a button. That way everything works fine.

The problem is when I try to replace my method from `viewDidLoad` and put it inside `IBAction`, the picture isn't rendered in social popup. Debugging shows my method returns what it should, an image, and it is fired on the touch of a button. Due to the fact there will be a change in the latest image while this viewController is loaded, calling it from `viewDidLoad` is not an option. Here is the code.

Method:

```
- (void) LastPic
{
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
    [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop) {
        if (alAsset) {
            ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [alAsset defaultRepresentation];
            UIImage *latestPhoto = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[representation fullScreenImage]];
            *stop = YES; *innerStop = YES;
            self.imageToShare = latestPhoto;
        }
    }];
} failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"No groups");
}];}
```

Action:

```
- (IBAction)ShareT:(id)sender {
[self LastPic]; //when in viewDidLoad everything kk
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]){
    self.slComposeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [self.slComposeViewController addImage:self.imageToShare];
    [self presentViewController:self.slComposeViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
else
{}}
```

I have all the necessary frameworks enabled and my h file looks like this. The same happens when I try to modify the code to pass the image as `NSData`.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *imageToShare;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because ALAssets is fetching in block. This means, you call Share controller when image is not fetched yet. I propose you add some progress hud like [this](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) with 2-3 seconds delay. This will solve your problem and it'll be friendly for the user. To check if it really works, test the code below:

```
- (void)fetchLastPhoto
{
    __block UIImage *latestPhoto;

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
    [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop) {
        if (alAsset)
        {
            ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [alAsset defaultRepresentation];
            latestPhoto = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[representation fullScreenImage]];
            _imageToShare = latestPhoto;
            *stop = YES; *innerStop = YES;
        }

        NSLog(@"Image fetched");
    }];
} failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"No groups");
}];
}

- (IBAction)buttonShare:(id)sender
{
    [self fetchLastPhoto];
    [self performSelector:@selector(openShareController) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0f];
}

-(void)openShareController
{
    NSLog(@"Share controller called");
    SLComposeViewController *slComposeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    [slComposeViewController addImage:self.imageToShare];
    [self presentViewController:slComposeViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```